# Swift charts framework - mark/highlight regions of LineChart?

Tags: swift, linechart, ios-charts

I am wondering if anyone knows of an elegant way to mark and highlight parts of a LineChart.

This could be done in a variety of ways, for example:

A. Using a dashed line "marked" regions of the graph

B. Shading the region underneath "marked" regions of the graph

ex: [Filled Area Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zmolj.png)

C. Using two distinct markers to distinguish the beginning and end of a "marked" region of the graph

The process of "marking" does not have to be touch-based - programmatic is OK too.

Any suggestions on implementation would be appreciated...thanks!

Comment: Can you add some image example of desirable result?

Comment: I added an example for the "filled area" to the OP. Thanks for the help btw, much appreciated!